# Does apache beam processing time, avoid late data?

Tags: apache-flink, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

If we are using beam streaming, with for example kafka source.
If we use the default processing timestamp, is it possible to have late data?

For example a pipeline like that:

> ```
>     pipeline
>      | "ReadFromKafka" >> ReadFromKafka()
>      | "WINDOW" >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(5))
>      | "DESERIALIZE REQUESTS" >> beam.Map(deserialize).with_output_types(Something)
>      | "YIELD MULTIPLE ITEMS" >> beam.ParDo(RandomLatency())
>      | "GROUP" >> beam.GroupByKey()
>      | "BIG PROCESSING" >> beam.ParDo(BigProcessing())
>  )
> ```

I understand that windows are not use until groupByKey, but for a given request in kafka, I will have a parDo that yield multiple items with the same key (I even split the pipeline and join with CoGroupByKey)

From my understanding, because I am using processing timestamp, my pipeline can't have late data, in my GroupByKey and CoGroupByKey  is it correct ?

Because watermark will always be behind of the data that enter the pipeline? Even if my groupby happen in late stage of the pipelines?